# After executing the following program i got some errors, need help to understand what the errors are and to clear it

Tags: verilog

code-

```
module try1(rb,reset,clk,sum,roll,win,lose);
input rb,reset,clk;
input [12:2]sum;
output roll,win,lose;
wire reg [5:0]state,nextstate;
wire reg [12:2]point;
wire reg sp;
always@(rb,reset,sum,state)
begin
    sp<=1'b0;                             // line 30
    roll<=1'b0;                           // line 31
    win<=1’b0;                            // line 32
    lose<=1’b0;                           //line 33
case(state)                               //line 34
    1’d0: if(rb==1)                       //line 35
                nextstate<=1’d1;          //line 36
    1’d1: if(rb==1) roll<=1’b1;           // line 37
            else if((sum==7)|(sum=11))    //line 38
                nextstate<=1’d2;          //line 39
            else if((sum==2)|(sum=3)|(sum=12))  
                nextstate<=1’d3;          //line 41
            else                          //line 42
                begin                     //line 43
                    sp<=1’b1;
                    nextstate<=1’d4;
                end
    1’d2: win<=1’b1;
            if(reset==1)
                nextstate<=1’d0;
    1’d3: lose<=1’b1;
            if(reset==1)
                nextstate<=1’d0;
    1’d4: if(rb==1)
                nextstate<=1’d5;
    1’d5: if(rb==1)
                roll<=1’b1;
            else if(sum=point)
                nextstate<=1’d2;
            else if(sum=7)
                nextstate<=1’d3;
            else
                nextstate<=1’d4;
endcase
end
always@(clk)
begin
    if(posedge (clk))
        state<=nextstate;
    if(sp==1)
        point<=sum;
end
endmodule

module gametest(rb,reset,sum,clk,roll,win,lose);
output rb,reset;
output[12:2] sum;
inout clk;
input roll,win,lose;
wire[3:0] tstate,tnext;
wire trig1;
wire i;
mem [11:0]arr;
parameter sumarray={7,11,2,4,7,5,6,7,6,8,9,6};
always #20 clk=~clk;
always@(roll,win,lose,tstate)
begin
case(tstate)
1’d0: rb=1’b1;
         Reset=1’b0;
         if(i>=12)
begin
tnext=1’d3;
else if(roll= =1)
begin
sum=sumarray[i];
i=i+1’d1;
tnext=1’d1;
end
end
1’d1:  rb=1’b0;
          Tnext=1’d2;
1’d2:  tnext=1’d0;
          Trig1=~trig1;
          if((win|lose) = =1) reset=1’b1;
1’d3: null;
endcase;
end
always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(clk= =1)  tsate=tnext;
end
endmodule

module test_tester();
reg/wire rb1,reset1,clk1,roll1,win1,lose1;
reg/wire [12:2] sum1;
dicegame d1(rb1,reset1,clk1,sum1,roll1,win1,lose1);
gametest g1(rb1,reset1,sum1,clk1, roll1,win1,lose1);
endmodule
```

After executing the above code i am getting the following errors:

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 30: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 31: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 32: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 33: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 35: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 36: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 37: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 39: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 41: Syntax error near " ".

"C:\Xilinx\project1\try1.v" Line 44: Syntax error near " ".

Comment: Verilog is not executed (in the sense of executing orders); it's synthesized :)

Comment: Rather than writing a large program and compiling it finally, always write small programs, with fewer features, then compile, then add a few features, compile again and so on. You seem to be writing the full intended program in one stretch without compiling in between. This makes debugging difficult.

Comment: Indeed, @MarcusMüller, either synthesized or simulated. It's not CPU instructions and there's no CPU so it's not executed. May sound to OPs like being fussy but it's imperative its seen as what it is :-)

Comment: Did u copy paste this code from somewhere and compile?

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be those ’ [(U+2019 : RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK)](https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) chars, that should actually be ' [(U+0027 : APOSTROPHE)](https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html).

But also errors such as the ones on line `else if((sum==7)|(sum=11))    //line 38` where you are "assigning" `sum=11` instead of comparing if they are equal `sum==11`.

And you also have problems with many of your literals (constant numbers) such as

```vhdl
case(state)                              //line 34
    1'd0: ...
endcase
```

where `1'd0` should be a single bit, but a few lines below you have `1’d5` **which will not be 5**, since it will truncate 5 into being 1 bit.

I listed a bunch of problems already, you should fix those and review a bit Verilog syntax. At the very least you will get different errors (that are already there but go unchecked due to these syntax ones that I pointed.)